# index_sequence usage for a class

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming

I want to create a class that will take the following input:

```
1,make_tuple('A',2,'B')
```

and inside the class a tuple with static type:

```
std::tuple<int,char,int,char>
```

and content of:

```
{1,'A',2,'B'}
```

should be created.

Kinda like this- but instead of a function returning the tuple- it should be a tuple that is a member variable of a class:

http://ideone.com/iu1wm5

I know I declare the tuple manually- but I intend to fix that after I figure out how to do this.

I havent found any examples of indicies and template classes- if you have a link to such an example that would also be great.

I know http://cpptruths.blogspot.dk/2012/06/perfect-forwarding-of-parameter-groups.html but he is using vectors- not tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cstddef>

template<class Ch, class Tr, class Tuple, std::size_t... Is>
void print_tuple_impl(std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& os,
                      const Tuple & t,
                      std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    using swallow = int[]; // guaranties left to right order
    (void)swallow {
        0, (void(os << (Is == 0 ? "" : ", ") << std::get<Is>(t)), 0)...
    };
}

template<class Ch, class Tr, class... Args>
auto operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& os, const std::tuple<Args...>& t)
-> std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>&
{
    os << "(";
    print_tuple_impl(os, t, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
    return os << ")";

}

template<class Tuple>
struct X {
    void print() const {
        std::cout << _tuple << std::endl;
    }
    Tuple _tuple;
};

template<class First, class...Rest>
struct myClass
{
    std::tuple<First, Rest...> myTuple;

    myClass(First parameterOne, std::tuple<Rest...> param2)
    : myTuple(std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(parameterOne),
                             param2))
    {

    }

    void print() const {
        std::cout << myTuple << std::endl;
    }
};

template<class First, class...Rest>
auto make_myClass(const First& f, const std::tuple<Rest...> rest)
-> myClass<First, Rest...>
{
    return { f, rest };
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto mine = make_myClass(1, make_tuple('a', 4));
    mine.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Hansvesselgård answer updated to reflect (and possibly exceed) requirements.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a class that will take the following input:

You don't need to create a class for such a thing. I'm not sure why you want a class that has just a member that is a `tuple`, that seems less useful than just having a `tuple`. Here's a genericized solution:

```
namespace details {
    template <typename T>
    struct is_tuple : std::false_type { };

    template <typename... Args>
    struct is_tuple<std::tuple<Args...>> : std::true_type { };

    // not a tuple? wrap it with std::make_tuple()
    template <typename T,
              std::enable_if_t<!is_tuple<std::decay_t<T>>::value>* = nullptr>
    auto as_tuple(T&& t) { return std::make_tuple(std::forward<T>(t));  }

    // is a tuple? 
    template <typename T,
              std::enable_if_t<is_tuple<std::decay_t<T>>::value>* = nullptr>
    decltype(auto) as_tuple(T&& t) { return std::forward<T>(t); }
}

template <typename... Args>
auto tuple_combiner(Args&&... args) {
    return std::tuple_cat(details::as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args))...);
}
```

Basically, `tuple_combiner` takes an arbitrary number of arguments which either are or aren't `tuple`s. We call `tuple_cat()` on a wrapped version of the arguments - the ones that are `tuple`s get forwarded through, and the ones that aren't get wrapped in a `tuple` first. We also forward everything to minimize copies: